# Highcharts-Export Server for Java JSON parsing issue

Tags: highcharts

I configured the highchart export server for Java from the current master in GitHub. When I tried to export an image using the demo page a corrupted file was returned.  I have debugged to code and found out the following message is returned as the result in validate method in ServerObjectFactory.java

String result = server.request("{\"status\":\"isok\"}");

The value of the result String is "Failed rendering:SyntaxError: Unable to parse JSON string"

What can be the cause for this issue.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

That's very strange. The syntax of the JSON string is syntactically correct. I can point out where from the error is generated.

In the highcharts-convert.js file in highcharts-ecport-convert/src/main/resources/phantomjs the incoming request is expected to be a JSON string and is parsed, see Line 469

```
function (request, response) {

var jsonStr = request.post,
    params,
    msg;
try {
    params = JSON.parse(jsonStr); // L469
    if (params.status) {
        // for server health validation
    response.statusCode = 200;
    response.write('OK');
    response.close();
    } else { 
       ....
```

Set in a `console.log(jsonStr)` before `JSON.parse(jsonStr)` . I hope this give you a clue of why it's throwing a error.

Comment: Actually I forgot to mention I deployed it in Weblogic server. After some debugging I moved in to tomcat and its working perfectly there. Not sure whats wrong with Weblogic in this regard.